# Using an abbreviation for noun AND verb (community garden/ing)

Tags: abbreviations

I am writing a paper about community gardening and use community garden(s) and community  gardening extensively. I would like to abbreviate both as CG. I can't find guidelines on if this is allowed (APA Style). My plan is to just list both community garden/community gardening as the definition in my abbreviations list. Thoughts?

Also, while I'm here. I know the general rule is to write (CG) after the first mention of community gardens and then abbreviate it afterwards, but is there any rule that I *must always* use the abbreviation after? For example, in my research question it seems more appropriate to write it out even though I have already defined CG before I introduce the research question. TLDR; can I choose not to abbreviate after defining the abbreviation?

Ok, and one more. If I have a direct quote that includes the written-out community gardening, should I abbreviate it within the quote or no? My gut feeling is no, but again can't find any info on this!

Comment: One would think _you_'d be the expert on pruning.

Comment: 1. No idea. 2. Of course. 3. Definitely not.

Comment: Thanks @MicahWindsor I'll run with this

Comment: You can do what you wish, but the question is: Why use the acronym *at all* if the only time you do is to define it? Doing that would seem like a wasted exercise. What's the point of not always just using the full term? If it's being used elsewhere, then I'd assume it's also defined elsewhere too. If you feel you need to explain the correlation to its use elsewhere, you could do something like this: "… community gardening (or *CG* in [other work])." That way it's a reference, but not an oddly "stranded" definition.

Comment: As for using an acronym to mean both noun and verb, that's fine. A word, spelled the same way, can also be used as a noun and verb. Context makes the meaning clear.

Comment: Last, if the quote uses the written-out version, that's what should be in the quote. You normally don't change what you quote. If you feel you have to abbreviate it for some reason, you would enclose it in square brackets to indicate that you have altered the original.